# OWIN HttpListener not located

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.5, owin, asp.net-web-api2

When I try to start :

```
WebApp.Start<SrvcHst>(new StartOptions { Port = 9956, 
     ServerFactory = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" });
```

I get the following exception. What could be the root cause?

```
System.MissingMemberException was caught
  HResult=-2146233070
  Message=The server factory could not be located for the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
  Source=Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveServerFactory(StartContext context)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
```

Comment: Is `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll` deployed with your app, next to the main assembly? Alternatively you can add it as a reference to this project and have it copied to the bin directory.

Comment: @MarcelN. Yes. It is already added as a reference to the project.

Comment: Similar issue: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/449301

Answer (score 131):

You have to include `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll` in your project references.

You can add it through NuGet.

However, if the code executing:

```
WebApp.Start<SrvcHst> (...);
```

is contained within a *class library*, **make sure that the *executable* consuming the library also includes the reference** to `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll`, or else it would not get deployed with your program, as there are no explicit references to it from the class library.

Have a look at your `bin/Debug` folder and make sure the DLL is there.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. A suggestion for improvement to your answer: I do not want to have to manually add that reference to all applications that will use my library. Instead I simply reference something (anything) inside the HttpListener assembly from my own assembly, so that the build is forced to bring along that DLL to the application's output folder.

Comment: Good point; indeed, you just have to make sure the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll` gets included. However that's done is up to you :-)

Comment: why is this not a dependency of  Microsoft.Owin.Hosting ?

Comment: You need to set bold  **make sure that the executable consuming the library also includes the reference**

Answer (score 47):

Make sure you have install package `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener`

To install package, use this command line :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```

Comment: I had a reference to this dll but for some reason it was not copied to the bin-Directory. I then tried your Suggestion to Install it via Nuget and it worked. Now it's copied to the Output-directory

Comment: You need to add reference to the HttpListener in the "StartUp Project". So, be carefull if you use `WebApp.Start` in another project.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes NuGet references are added in an incomplete state. If you have the packages installed, however references are not included, try reinstalling them via;

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

in the package manager console.

Comment: I also tried to use Update-Package -reinstall but in the middle of the process there was an error and all packages havee been deleted. I manually had to add all references again...so be careful ;)

Comment: Simply restore packages.config from source control, or make sure you backup beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to Pierre's and Damith's answer. If you are using **Mac OS**, run the following command to install **HttpListener**:

```
dnu install Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```